# Is it possible to constrain a generic type defined in a jsDoc @template declaration?

Tags: generics, typescript, mixins

We'd like to define [mixin classes](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13743) in regular .js files using jsDoc comments instead of .ts files.

An important aspect of mixin classes is constraining the generic type parameter to a class constructor using `extends`. E.g., the above page has the following TypeScript:

```
type Constructor<T> = new(...args: any[]) => T;
function Tagged<T extends Constructor<{}>>(Base: T) { ... }
```

TypeScript's jsDoc support allows for a `@template T` declaration, but we don't see any way to constrain `T` to, for example, be a class constructor. Is there some way to do that?

We'd be willing to create/use `.d.ts` files to support this, as long as the mixin declaration itself can exist in a .js file, and that `checkJs` will appropriately type-check the workings of that .js file.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1178

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24283

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of TypeScript 2.9 it seems constraining template parameters is now possible using TypeScript (see [issue 24600](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24600)). The above TypeScript declaration would therefor become:

```js
/**
 * @template T
 * @typedef {new(...args: any[]) => T} Constructor
 **/

/**
 * @template {Constructor<{}>} T
 * @param {T} Base
 */
function Tagged(Base) { … }
```