# Documenting classes that are generated through functions (mixing)

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I'm trying to document the following code but I seem to be unable to make JSDoc document that class or even reference it's existence.

```js
// SomeMixin.js 
export default superclass => class SomeMixin extends superclass {
   // class code goes here
   func() {}
};
```

```js
import SomeMixin from './SomeMixin';
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

/**
 * @param {SomeMixin} bar
 */
function foo(bar) {

}

class MyClass extends SomeMixin(EventEmitter) {}

const item = new MyClass();

foo(bar);
```

How can I document this code so that JSDoc sees that `SomeMixin` can be inherited (is a class) and that when I make an instance of `MyClass` that it inherits the method `func`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update

With the help of https://stackoverflow.com/a/52335792/5458200 I got:

```js
// SomeMixin.js
/**
 * @template T
 * @typedef {new(...args: any[]) => T} Constructor
 **/

/**
 * @template {Constructor<{}>} T
 * @param {T} superclass
 */
function mixin(superclass) {
  return class SomeMixin extends superclass {
    // class code goes here
    func() {}
  };
}

export default mixin
```

```js
// index.js
import createMixin from "./SomeMixin";
import { EventEmitter } from "events";

/**
 *
 * @param {MyClass} bar
 */
function foo(bar) {
  bar;
}

class MyClass extends createMixin(EventEmitter) {}

const item = new MyClass();

foo(item);
```

[image: solution 2]

---

Here is a version that I tried. Not the best solution but in VSCode I can see `func` and methods from `EventEmitter`.

```js
// SomeMixin.js
import { EventEmitter } from "events";

/**
 * @param {EventEmitter} superclass
 */
function mixin(superclass) {
  /**
   * @extends EventEmitter
   */
  class SomeMixin extends superclass {
    // class code goes here
    func() {}
  }

  return SomeMixin;
}

export default mixin;
```

```js
// index.js
import SomeMixin from "./SomeMixin";
import { EventEmitter } from "events";

class MyClass extends SomeMixin(EventEmitter) {}

const item = new MyClass();
```

[image: solution 1]

But still, need to figure out how to work with Generic Types. Probably [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017627/document-generic-type-parameters-in-jsdoc) may help.